# Permissions issues with Office365 Sharepoint, Owner account

Tags: sharepoint-2010, permissions, office365

I have just been tasked with overseeing an Office365 Sharepoint team site, and there is a very odd legacy issue that was left unresolved by the last administrator. We have the standard set of groups that you would expect to see (visitors, members, owners) and one of the folks here is in both the Members (contribute) and Owners (full control) permission groups.

However, her ability to access things is... strange. She can view most everything, and add new content to most everything (lists, forms, etc.) But she cannot edit any documents, list items, etc. Nor can she delete items.

Is there a way that her permissions (full control) could be in conflict with another setting? What should I look for to investigate further?

All help will be greatly appreciated, as this is quite mysterious.

Cross-listed at: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58306/permissions-issues-with-office365-sharepoint-owner-account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look at the document libraries and lists in question, by default they inherit permissions but this can be changed.  Select the library and select the permissions icon from the top ribbon to check to see what that particular user's rights are for the items in question.

Comment: I'm going to take that as a good answer, because I believe it would be correct in nearly all situations.  For my situation, it is only this particular user having this issue, and only with internet explorer.  I moved her to using Firefox and that is how we're "making do."

Comment: Are you guys still on SharePoint 2010 or have you moved to wave 15?  Is the behavior the same on multiple workstations?

Comment: It is just the one user, and we were only seeing the behavior on her machine.  And our Sharepoint is via Office365.